# Angular 5: Passing an array from child to parent component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I have a child and a parent component.

I want to pass an array from the child component and display it in the parent component.

I first started with:

```
@Input data: string[];
```

Then in `ngOnInit` I have:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.data = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'];
}
```

Then I have the parent component:

```
<app.parent></app.parent>
```

My question is: how do I display this data in the parent component?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be using `@Output()` as below,

```
@Output() data: EventEmitter<string[]> = new EventEmitter<string[]>();

ngOnInit() {
   this.data.emit(['name1', 'name2', 'name3']);
}
```

you should be handling the event in your parent as

```
<app.parent (data)="eventHandler($event)"></app.parent>

eventHandler(event:string[]){
     this.childData = event;
}
```

Display the `childData` in your component as

```
{{childData}}
```

Comment: I'm confused on which parts of the code go in which files...can you please specify?

Comment: Can you create a plunker to reproduce your error. I'll write on top of it and help you

Comment: I've deleted all me code and I'm going to use your code. I have child-component and parent-component and also the app.component ... You have 3 sections in your code. I just need to know what files they go into. Could you just specify that?

Comment: First code should be in your child and remaining code should be in your typescript and html of parent component

Comment: childData does not exist on parent component